# Can't connect to linked container in the same Docker network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have run two Docker services in a docker-compose file, in a network that I have previously created:

```
version: '3'
services:

  api:
    container_name: api
    //blah blah
    networks:
    - mynetwork
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
    - 8080:8080 

  networks:
    mynetwork:
```

This is the api's Dockerfile (NodeJS):

```
FROM node

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

CMD npm start
```

Then, I'm running another container (nginx with static webapp) in the same network (mynetwork), linked with `api`.

```
docker run --rm --net=mynetwork --link api:api -p 80:80 myimage
```

and the Dockerfile (NGINX with React app):

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY ./build /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

But it's not able to connect to `api`. When I `sh` inside my webapp's container and ping to `api`, I get this:

```
$ ping api
$ ping: bad address 'api'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you fill out your `api` service entry in the docker-compose.yml? The contents do matter. It would also be beneficial to include the Dockerfile for the `api` service.

Comment: @bluescores edited!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! docker-compose file was bad configured. `mynetwork` already exists so I need to use this configuration:

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: mynetwork
```

instead of:

```
  networks:
    mynetwork:
```

And remove `networks` key from the declared services.